# Catching excel data to a list variable in python

Tags: python

Is it possible to catch data and put it on a list variable? Not like variable args..

```
    get_row = Instant.getRowCount(self, "..\\TestData\\TestData.xlsx", "TestData")
    for o in range(get_row):
        boom = Instant.readDataFile(self, "..\\TestData\\TestData.xlsx", "TestData", o + 1, 5)
        if not boom is None:
            print(o) # The number produce here are the one i need
            # I want to get all values in 'o'after the loop is done like variable = [{o}]
```

The actual result of this are : 1, 14, 26.

I want to pass that values to another loop

Thanks guys. Sorry

EDITED: Tried adding to list then appending it but it only produce 1 number "26"

```
    get_row = Instant.getRowCount(self, "..\\TestData\\TestData.xlsx", "TestData")
    for o in range(get_row):
        boom = Instant.readDataFile(self, "..\\TestData\\TestData.xlsx", "TestData", o + 1, 5)
        if not boom is None:
            # print(o) # The number produce here are the one i need
            my_list = list()
            my_list.append(o)
            print(my_list)
    print(new_list)
```

The output file is [26]

Comment: To clarify, right now the loop prints 1, 14, 26? Can you create a list before the loop and then in the if statement append o to the list?

Comment: it prints this way
1
14
26

but manage to answer my question. :)

Comment: `if not boom is None:` ?    `if boom is not None:`    !

Comment: sorry my bad. already updated that when i'm refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

I created a local variable then append that on the loop. My bad creating it inside the loop. it will replace all the value inside that why it prints the last number

```
    new_list = []
    get_row = Instant.getRowCount(self, "..\\TestData\\TestData.xlsx", "TestData")
    for o in range(get_row):
        boom = Instant.readDataFile(self, "..\\TestData\\TestData.xlsx", "TestData", o + 1, 5)
        if not boom is None:
            new_list.append(o)

     for p in range(new_range):
        data_to_read = Instant.readDataFile(self, '..\\Test\\ConvertedFiles\\CSVConverted.xlsx', "csv_file", aaa+p, 2)
        Instant.writeDataFile(self, "..\\TestData\\TestData.xlsx", "TestData", new_list[p] + 1, 5, data_to_read)
```

Comment: I'll try this one out. Thx!